# how to handle page refresh with $stateProvider as page goto previous state on refresh in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want to handle page refesh with $stateProvider in my login page their is a forgot pwd link when i click on the link forgot pwd page appears as per the routing code , but now i got an issue that when i refresh my forgot pwd page my page gets redirected to login page , kindly tell me how can i resolve that ?

here is my login.html page with forgot pwd link:

```
<div class="input-element-row">
                <div class="forgot-pass"><a ui-sref="forgot">Forgot password?</a></div>
            </div>
```

here is my router.js containing routing code:

```
angular.module("nk.login", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate'
  ]).
    config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
      $stateProvider
        .state('app.login', {
          url: '/login',
          views: {
            "content": {
              templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/login.html',
              controller: 'loginController'
            }
          }
        })
          .state('app.forgotPassword', {
              url: '/forgot',
              views: {
                  "content": {
                      templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/forgotPassword.html',
                      controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
                  }
              }
          })
    }]);
```

here is my forgotpwd.html page:

```
<div class="inputs-container">
            <form name="forgotPassword" novalidate>
                <div class="input-element-row">
                    <div class="rgt-input-box fl"><span class="center-icon action-icon"></span><input type="text"
                    ng-model="Nuser.center_code" placeholder="Center Code" name="CenterCode" value=""
                          ng-pattern = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/" maxlength="5" required ng-disabled="isDisable"/></div>
                    <div class="cb">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-element-row">
                    <div class="rgt-input-box fl"><span class="user-icon action-icon"></span><input type="text"
                    placeholder="User ID"  ng-model="Nuser.login_id" name="UserID" value=""
                    ng-pattern = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/" maxlength="10" required ng-disabled="isDisable"/></div>
                    <div class="cb"></div>
                </div>




                <div class="input-element-row">
                    <button type="button" name="send"  ng-click="send(userLogin)">Send</button>

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your routing can be simplified as follows

```
angular.module("nk.login", [
'ngRoute',
'ngAnimate'
]).
config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController'
    })
      .state('app.forgotPassword', {
       url: '/forgot',
       templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/forgotPassword.html',
       controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
      })
}]);
```

Is there any specific reason for the views/content property?

Comment: i am doing one part of an application and i am new too so dont know xactly much about it , but i tried doing with your code its simply not working , soo i guess i cant edit that content part